# compare directories to check if one is sub-directory of another

Tags: java, file, arraylist, directory, comparison

I have an arraylist of directories in the root of the class, `ArrayList<File> sources`, and a method `addNewSource` to add new directories in the list.

```
private void addNewSource(File src){
    sources.add(src);
}
```

Now I need to add a new method to check if the new source is a sub-directory of existing directories in the list. Lets assume the arraylist have following directories:

```
["D:\", "E:\", "F:\"]
```

Now I am going to add two new directories, one `"G:\"` and another `"D:\Folder\"`. The new method should return `false` for the **first** and `true` for **second** one.

**Simple Solution I Found:**

Go to the parent directory and check if it exist in the list until we reach the root directory. It get my work done but takes a lot of time when working with big list (1000 directories) and the new directory is inside 1500 parent directories.

Do you have or know any better and optimized solution for this problem that won't take long processing time. please no external library.

Comment: Replace the “big list” with a set, e.g. a `HashSet`. This might accelerate your operation by roughly factor 1000. Regarding the number of parent directories, I have difficulties with believing you. “1500 parent directories”? Sounds ridiculous to me…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that you don't need to look at each 'part' of `src` to see if it is contained in `sources`.  Rather, you can do something like:

```
ArrayList<File> sources = new ArrayList<>();
boolean addNewSourceToList(File src) throws IOException
{
    Path newPath = src.toPath();
    for(File f : sources)
    {           
        if(newPath.startsWith(f.toPath()))
        {
            return true;            
        }   
    }
    sources.add(src);
    return false;
}
```

Essentially, the `startsWith()` method does the part-by-part comparison for us.

Of course, this algorithm still requires looking at every element (in the worst case) in `sources` each time the method is called.  So if `sources` contains a 1000 items, it will need to do 1000 `startsWith()` comparisons.

As @Holger suggested, a much better approach is to use a `Set` instead of a `List`.  However the `Set.contains()` method is based on the element's `.equals()`, and as that (for `File` or `Path`) doesn't have the notion of 'sub-directories', we need need to do something a bit special: we need to see if each 'part' of `src` is in `sources`.

```
Set<Path> sourcesSet = new HashSet<>();
boolean addNewSourceToSet(File src) throws IOException
{
    Path newPath = src.toPath();
    // See if contained exactly
    if(sourcesSet.contains(newPath))
    {
        return true;            
    }
    Path parent = newPath.getParent();

    while(parent != null)
    {
        if(sourcesSet.contains(parent))
        {
            return true;
        }
        parent = parent.getParent();                    
    }
    sourcesSet.add(newPath);
    return false;
}
```

If we can assume that `src` will contains significantly less than 1000 parts, the algorithm will run much quicker, as it will only run the `contains()` method once for every part of `src`.